# Spring-Security: Difference Between /** and /* url pattern in Spring-Security

Tags: java, security, spring-security, url-pattern

I am little bit confuse with URL-pattern in spring security. Because, in servlet core http security, the `/` and `/*` url patterns are used for specify one or more directories. `/` is use for one directory and `/*` is used of many directories. But in spring-security, the `/**` is also introduce, what is the main purpose of `/**` url-pattern in security.

Answer (score 34):

The difference between /* & /** is that the second matches the entire directory tree, including subdirectories, where as /* only matches at the level it's specified at.

Answer (score 16):

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ...
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/*").permitAll
    // ...
 }
```

In this configuration any "**Get**" request will be permitted, for example:

- /book
- /book/20
- /book/20/author

So, all this urls match text with pattern "/**".

Permitted urls for "**Post**":

- /book
- /magazine

Urls above match with "/*"

Answer (score 8):

According to Spring Security documentation the main purpose of `/**` is to catch-all wildcards:

> In practice we recommend that you use method security at your service layer, to control access to your
>   application, and do not rely entirely on the use of security constraints defined at the web-application level.
>   URLs change and it is difficult to take account of all the possible URLs that an application might support and
>   how requests might be manipulated. You should try and restrict yourself to using a few simple ant paths which
>   are simple to understand. Always try to use a “deny-by-default” approach where you have a catch-all wildcard
>   (/** or **) defined last and denying access.

We also should not forget that

> Patterns are always evaluated in the order they are defined. Thus it is important that more specific patterns are defined higher in the list than less specific patterns.

Thus we can have something like this:

```
<security:http pattern="/rest-service/**"  authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" auto-config="false" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest-service/report/export/xml" access="AUTH_REPORT_EXPORTXML" />        
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="AUTH_SYSTEM_LOGIN" />
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>
```

which means that for all requests we will need AUTH_SYSTEM_LOGIN authority, but specifically for /rest-service/report/export/xml the user will need AUTH_REPORT_EXPORTXML authority as well because it is defined above. As they also say it is better not rely only on this security constrains which means that it is good also to duplicate those in service methods with secured annotation like this:

```
@Secured("AUTH_REPORT_EXPORTXML")
```

In general as I understand there is no difference between `/*` and `/**` except that the last one catches all the wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

"/api/v1/user/*" - will match any value, up to another "/"

"/api/v1/user/**" - will match all values beginning with start of string (including if another "/" is found.